# Storing .csv in HDF5 pandas

Tags: pandas, hdf5

I was experimenting with HDF and it seems pretty great because my data is not normalized and it contains a lot of text. I love being able to query when I read data into pandas.

```
    loc2 = r'C:\\Users\Documents\\'
    (my dataframe with data is called 'export')
    hdf = HDFStore(loc2+'consolidated.h5')
    hdf.put('raw', export, format= 'table', complib= 'blosc', complevel=9, data_columns = True, append = True)
```

21 columns and about 12 million rows so far and I will add about 1 million rows per month.

- 1 Date column [I convert this to datetime64]
- 2 Datetime columns (one of them for each row and the other one is null about 70% of the time) [I convert this to datetime64]
- 9 text columns [I convert these to categorical which saves a ton of room]
- 1 float column
- 8 integer columns, 3 of these can reach a max of maybe a couple of hundred and the other 5 can only be 1 or 0 values

I made a nice small h5 table and it was perfect until I tried to append more data to it (literally just one day of data since I am receiving daily raw .csv files). I received errors which showed that the dtypes were not matching up for each column although I used the same exact ipython notebook.

- Is my hdf.put code correct? If I have append = True does that mean it will create the file if it does not exist, but append the data if it does exist? I will be appending to this file everyday basically.
- For columns which only contain 1 or 0, should I specify a dtype like int8 or int16 - will this save space or should I keep it at int64? It looks like some of my columns are randomly float64 (although no decimals) and int64. I guess I need to specify the dtype for each column individually. Any tips?
- I have no idea what blosc compression is. Is that the most efficient one to use? Any recommendations here? This file is mainly used to quickly read data into a dataframe to join to other .csv files which Tableau is connected to